# Wrong intersection position between curve and vertical line

Tags: pgfplots, intersections

In my example below, the point of intersection between the green curve (`name path = curve`) and the vertical line (`name path = vertical`) is wrong, also I get an Package pgf Error: `No shape named intersection-1 is known. \end{axis}` What is wrong in my example?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-0.4, xmax=1, ymin=-10, ymax=60, axis lines = center,
clip=true,
width=13cm,
height=13cm,
xlabel={$r$},
x label style={at={(axis cs:1,0)},
anchor=north,
font=\normalsize},
ylabel={$U_{eff}$},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.15,1)},
anchor=south,
rotate=0,
font=\normalsize},
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot[name path=curve, ultra thick, green, domain=0.05:1,samples=1000]{1/x^2-0.05/x^3};
\draw [name path = vertical] (axis cs:0.2,50) -- (axis cs:0.2,-10) ;
\draw [name intersections={of=curve and vertical, by=Pe}] (Pe) -- (axis cs:0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `samples` smaller than 1000. It works for me with `samples=500`. If that doesn't look smooth enough, you can add the keyword `smooth`. There is a warning in the `tikz` manual against trying to find the intersections of plots with "lots of very small segments".

Comment: @Dan you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a warning in the `tikz` manual against trying to find the intersections of plots with "lots of very small segments". So perhaps `samples=1000` is too large. It turns out that for this particular plot, using `samples=500` works for me. If that doesn't look smooth enough (there appears to be a tiny kink at the peak of the plot), you can add the keyword `smooth`:

```
\addplot[name path=curve, ultra thick, green, %
  domain=0.05:1,samples=500, smooth]{1/x^2-0.05/x^3};
```